# MySQL Update Query Successfull But Values Doesn't Changing At All

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a problem, I created a stored procedure to activate users by sending their email id and activation key

this is the SQL syntax (in MySQL)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dbname`.`sp_userActivate` (
    IN email VARCHAR(140),
    IN ac VARCHAR(64)
)
BEGIN
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE user SET activated = 1
    WHERE user.email = email AND 
      user.activation_key=ac;
commit;
END
```

When I execute the syntax, it's successfully executed, but when I take a look in the table, the value activated still remains = 0 (not updated at all)

I have looked more than twice to ensure the email and activation is equal with is stored in table,

What's wrong with this Query?

**UPDATE**

This is my table structure in schema

[image: Table Design]

Thanks in advance for your help.

SQL Statement for Create table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`user` (

`no` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
`firstname` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL ,
`lastname` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL ,
`pepper` CHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
`activation_key` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`gender` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`activated` CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_bin' NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`no`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username` ASC) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email` ASC) ,
INDEX `user_firstname_idx` (`firstname` ASC) ,
INDEX `user_lastname_idx` (`lastname` ASC) )
```

For Example Row

```
insert into 
user(username, password,firstname, lastname, email,pepper,activation_key,gender)
values("usr1test","c781bf44a464a5946ef36a7250f5504388914bbf6287fabaf938472f46c413d71cd7bf2b3077eeac8675419d5f022ff3652ba7e13e8","user1","test","usr1test@localhost","af41bfa3c9324f39fd82f84125967b38969662256cf8249e73e3bd2cef3928b5","OGE4Y2E2OWUtMmM2Mi00MjJkLWI0NTQtNzJkZDQ1OTcxNjUx",'M');
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer, based on that, can you remove `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` and `COMMIT;` and try to execute again.

Comment: Hi @JW웃 thanks for your respose again, i have tried with that method, but still not working. I think there is something wrong with activation_key value.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: here's the example:

email: usr1test@localhost
activationkey: OGE4Y2E2OWUtMmM2Mi00MjJkLWI0NTQtNzJkZDQ1OTcxNjUx

anyway. both of columns are varchar type

Comment: how do you check the query result exactly? Do you use the console? Do you start a new session each time? Also, how do you run the procedure? What about your server settings? Did you change anything regarding autocommit or transaction isolation?

Comment: @didierc hi, i use MySQL workbench to create the query and execute the stored procedure as usual just call <procedure name> | for server setings, it's runs on Windows 7 Prof machine (x86) with XAMPP version 3.1.0. MySQL server version community: v5.5.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the procedure, that worked for me:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_userActivate;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_userActivate (
    IN email VARCHAR(140),
    IN ac VARCHAR(64)
)
BEGIN
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
    UPDATE `user`
        SET activated = 1
        WHERE 
            `user`.`email` = email
        AND 
      `user`.`activation_key` = ac;
    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Run this, then try:

```
CALL sp_userActivate('usr1test@localhost', 
'OGE4Y2E2OWUtMmM2Mi00MjJkLWI0NTQtNzJkZDQ1OTcxNjUx');
```

It worked correctly on my machine.

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i just updated the information as described above. can you see the updated section please?

from information above i see you update based on 'key', but in my condition, i want to change specific column.

Comment: @randytan Can you provide CREATE TABLE statement plus 2 rows of sample data (like I did in the answer), so I could fully reproduce your error?

Comment: if this working on your machine, what's wrong with my machine? what MySQL version do you use?

Comment: @randytan 5.5 on Windows XP. If you want, I can create a chat room for us to avoid prolonged comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30682/discussion-between-randytan-and-user4035)

Comment: @didierc It was incorrect data in the table. He had plain text data in the database and tried to compare it with hash.

Comment: @didierc, actually i still don't have an answer about this problem. When i use UPDATE statement for plain text eg. WHERE act_key = 123 it works perfectly. I need to try my code in different machine then.

Answer (score 0):

okay, after see the table data in my table. It seems that the key is have BLANK space after the last character.

example :

1. -- with blank space:
   ZWRhNzZmMzMtMmI2Ny00NDBlLTkxNTUtNmQ2MWIwYjg3MzA4_ (see _ ?)
2. -- without blank space: ZWRhNzZmMzMtMmI2Ny00NDBlLTkxNTUtNmQ2MWIwYjg3MzA4

so, the MySQL see point no 1 and 2 are different.

I hope this makes my problem clear.

thank you for all of the contributor

Comment: @user4035 i think this is the answer why i couldn't update my table :D